# Spring boot 3.0.1, I have 2 Strange errors in CreateQuery() function and @Autowire adnnotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, annotations

[image: 1]

I have this strange error, the code is working, but the queryone is strange anyway and annoy. Thanks - hoping there is a solution

I searched almost everywhere for a solution, I didn't find anything helpful

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate 6 expects implicit SELECT clause in front now, however the old query still compiles, it is recommended now to add SELECT as well.

`SELECT e FROM Employee e`

EntityManager autowiring error is most likely only because of IntelliJ cannot find the correct configuration for this bean, but should work fine at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming from your IDE, or more precisely from some IDE plugin.

I don't know what plugin you're using, but I imagine that the plugin is validating that the query is syntactically correct *JPQL*, and is not accepting one of HQL's *many* extensions to the syntax of JPQL.

Your query is perfectly legal *HQL*, for the record.